# Cannot get the value of the key of response returned from graph api

Tags: php

** **Used guzzle for HTTP request of Microsoft graph API to get the delta link of one drive.****

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $deltaUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root/delta?deltaToken=latest';
            $deltaLink = json_decode($client->request('get', $deltaUrl, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => $this->token,
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Content-type' => 'application/json',
                ]
            ])->getBody()->getContents());
```

**Returned Response is like**

````
["@odata.context"]=>
string(64) "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)"
["@odata.deltaLink"]=>
string(287)
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives('b!qr6_XPV0S0qNpOz8TMRdZIB0lzTYzKlJpLDrr8K98DuIA1lgGJHzSr7mwkS_W6_k')/root/microsoft.graph.delta(token='MzslMjM0OyUyMzE7Mzs2MDU5MDM4OC05MTE4LTRhZjMtYmVlNi1jMjQ0YmY1YmFmZTQ7NjM3NTgxNDU0ODUxMDAwMDAwOzI3NzU5NjUyNTslMjM7JTIzOyUyMzA')?deltaToken=latest"
["value"]=>
array(0) {
}
}```


**How can I get the value of key ["@odata.deltaLink"]** ??
````

Comment: try json_decode($client, true)

Comment: _“Returned Response is like”_ - looks like a var_dump output, but with large parts cut off. Still, looks like a simple array, so where exactly is the problem to access the value you are looking for via its key, as usual?